# Add NA based on previous column

Tags: r

my dataframe looks like this:

```
Total   Taxes   VAT Debit   Credit  Department  Personal    Car
17.5    0.5     no    x       NA       yes         no       yes
72.5    0.5     no    x       NA       yes         yes      no
1.4      NA     no    x       NA       yes         no       yes
4.5      NA     no    x       NA       yes         no       yes
1.5      NA     no    x       NA       yes         no       yes
```

and I want that in `department`, `personal` and `car` my output displays `NA` instead. The `NA` is based on the `taxes` column. For instance, if there is a `NA` in `taxes`, then there should be a `NA` in the following columns like in the example below:

```
Total   Taxes   VAT Debit   Credit  Department  Personal    Car
17.5     0.5    no    x      NA         yes        no       yes
72.5     0.5    no    x      NA         yes        yes      no
1.4      NA     no    NA     NA         NA         NA       NA
4.5      NA     no    NA     NA         NA         NA       NA
1.5      NA     no    NA     NA         NA         NA       NA
```

Is there a solution in `BaseR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a index based on 'Taxes' and assign the columns of interest to `NA` in `base R`

```
i1 <- is.na(df1$Taxes)
colsOfInterest <- c('Debit', 'Department', 'Personal', 'Car')
df1[i1, colsOfInterest] <- NA
df1
#  Total Taxes VAT Debit Credit Department Personal  Car
#1  17.5   0.5  no     x     NA        yes       no  yes
#2  72.5   0.5  no     x     NA        yes      yes   no
#3   1.4    NA  no  <NA>     NA       <NA>     <NA> <NA>
#4   4.5    NA  no  <NA>     NA       <NA>     <NA> <NA>
#5   1.5    NA  no  <NA>     NA       <NA>     <NA> <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` way would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Department:Car), funs(replace(., is.na(Taxes), NA)))

# Total Taxes VAT Debit Credit Department Personal  Car
#1  17.5   0.5  no     x     NA        yes       no  yes
#2  72.5   0.5  no     x     NA        yes      yes   no
#3   1.4    NA  no     x     NA       <NA>     <NA> <NA>
#4   4.5    NA  no     x     NA       <NA>     <NA> <NA>
#5   1.5    NA  no     x     NA       <NA>     <NA> <NA>
```